# Pass parametr to directEvents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net

How pass value `colum ID (.DataIndex("ID"))`  to Action in Controller?

```
  @(Html.X().GridPanel()
                                            .Title("ComponentColumn Pin Editor")
                                            .Width(700)
                                            .Height(300)
                                            .Store(Html.X().Store()
                                                .Model(Html.X().Model()
                                                    .Fields(
                                                        new ModelField("ID", ModelFieldType.Int),

                                                    )
                                                )
                                                .DataSource(Model)
                                            )   
      .ColumnModel(
                                        Html.X().ComponentColumn()
                                            .Editor(true)
                                            .OverOnly(true)
                                            .Pin(true)
                                            .DataIndex("ID")
                                            .Flex(1)
                                            .Text("ID")
                                            .Component(Html.X().NumberField())
      Html.X().GridCommand()
                                .CommandName("Edit")
                                .Icon(Icon.NoteEdit)
                                    .ToolTip(t =>
                                    {
                                        t.Text = "Modifica della ripartizione ferie per giorno";
                                    })
                                )
                                .ID("ID")
                            .DirectEvents(

                                    directEvents =>
                                    {
                                        //  directEvents.Command.Url = "/Details/ID";
                                        directEvents.Command.Action = "Details";
                                        directEvents.Command.ExtraParams.Add(new Parameter()
                                        {
                                            Name = "ID",
                                            Value="ID",
                                        //    Value = "App.GridPanelDistributionReports.getSelectionSubmit().getSelectionModelField().getValue()",
                                            Mode = ParameterMode.Raw
                                        });
                                    })

                    )
```

I need send value from gridTable to Action function.

In Example I saw this:

```
  Value = "App.GeneratedDistributionId.getValue()",
```

but I not undestand, how use it. 
What is "GeneratedDistributionId"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give ID to objects (gridpanel, store, etc) for accessing on client side (js). I think **GeneratedDistributionId** auto generated value by ext.net for your app. You need you set your grid panel ID as **GridPanelDistributionReports**. Then you can access it.

Add **debugger;** command to your js like below, for code waiting you while developer tools enabled:

```
Value = "debugger;App.GridPanelD..."
```

Then check you js code is correct or not in debugging mode.